# Send keys to app in background / send keys to other app without losing focus of current app

Tags: macos, applescript, catalina, automator

How can I make some automated service type something in a non-focussed application without making that other application the frontmost?

I found a [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53691845/3310334) which suggests using AppleScript:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Google Chrome"
        set frontmost to true
        key code 4
        key code 14
        key code 37
        key code 35
    end tell
end tell
```

Unfortunately at the time of that answer in 2018 there were apparently no ways to make this AppleScript and its target application run in the background.

How can I simulate keyboard input to a background application on macOS Catalina 10.15.5?

Comment: **System Events** can only send _keystrokes_ to the frontmost _window_, it cannot send _keystrokes_ to a _window_ that's in the background.

Comment: @user3439894 how about other solutions that are not System Events?

Comment: This same type question as been asked many times and I have never seen an answer to send _keystrokes_ to a background _window_. I'd imaging it would take some sort of  C, C++, or Obj-C type level programing. Possibly JavaScript if it's a browser that supports it.

Comment: It looks like you're wanting to write the word `"help"` into--I'm guessing--a text box in Chrome. `keystroke "help"` would have been more obvious, but neither will go to a background process.  However, as @user3439894 stated, JavaScript can do this by injecting it directly into a Chrome webpage. You can send the JavaScript command using AppleScript: e.g. `tell app "Chrome" to execute in tab 1 of window 1 javascript "document.querySelector(...).value=..."`. The JS portion will depend very much on your specific situation (i.e. the webpage).

Comment: @CJK I also don't know how to simulate keypresses with javascript. I can substitute the value directly as in your example, but it's important to simulate a human in this case.

Comment: @theonlygusti Why ?