# How do I focus an application in the background with AppleScript. Trying to automate a key press in the background. (not keystroke)

Tags: mac, applescript, automation

Trying to automate a key press. In Automator, recording a watch me do allows for things to be done in a targeted app. When played, this recording can even run in the background but for some reason, looping the action over time slowly causes me to lag, forcing me to force quit and run it again. To avoid this I tried making my own in AppleScript.

```
tell application "Notes" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    delay 1 (*delay time in seconds before program starts*)
    set timesToRepeat to 100 (*times for the program to repeat*)
    set delayTime to 2 (*delay time in seconds between mouse clicks*)
    repeatTimesToRepeat times
        key code 18
        delay delayTime
    end repeat
end tell
```

The problem is with system events I believe. Although the key is pressed when the window is at the forefront, when I tab out it stops doing it to the Notes and then focuses on my other windows that I view. Removing system events causes a syntax error with key code.

I need help in focusing on a specific application or like their window but be able to switch off and go to another.

Comment: related if not dupe: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/392590/150109

Comment: Just read it and it seems those guys didn't find a solution. I thought automator and applescript were same language. Maybe theres a way.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, to send keystrokes/keypresses to an application it must be “in focus” which means it’s no longer in the background.

Comment: Automator can use AppleScript via the Run AppleScript action, but for System Events to script an application’s user interface, that interface needs to be active.

Comment: @Allan Then how does automator do it? Unless it doesn't use applescript.